# How can I insert "typical" field values on CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

When I have several documents where there is a field which value is selected from a small groups of choices, is there any tool that prevents from introducing a wrong value?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, [validation functions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation) sound like what you need. All the validation functions (1 per design document, as many design documents per database as you need) are run before each write. If any validation function throws an error, the write is refused.

Comment: Thank you. What I am looking for is some kind of LookUp Table or Multi-select form.

Comment: You'll have to "hard-code" all your possible values into your validation function, they can't reference anything outside that view.